# Conditional Expectation of Poisson variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $X \sim exp(\lambda)$ be a random variable. For a given value of $X$, let $Y,Z \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(X)$ be two Poisson random variables. I try to calculate $E(Y\mid Z)$. I tried first to find $E(Y\mid X),E(X\mid Z)$. The first term is trivial, but I'm not sure how to find out $E(X\mid Z)$ (actually I'm not even sure that these calculations give the right answer at the end. Does total expectation law simply solve it?)

Comment: Are $Y,Z$ independent given the outcome of $X$?

Comment: @FormulaWriter yes of course

Comment: For $z \in \{0,1, 2, ...\}$ you want $$E[Y|Z=z] = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} y P[Y=y|Z=z]$$ and, assuming $Y, Z$ are conditionally independent given $X$, you can get $P[Y=y|Z=z]$ by conditioning on $X=x$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Micheal Since $P(X=x)=0$, how can we condition on  $X=x$?

Comment: For descrete case $X\in [n]$, we would say $$P[Y=y|Z=z]=\underset {x\in [n]} \Sigma P[Y=y|X=x,Z=z] =$$
$$\underset {x\in [n]} \Sigma \frac {P[Y=y,X=x,Z=z]} {P[X=x,Z=z]}$$ So in the continuous case we just should use the PDF of $X$ for given $Z$, that is $$P[Y=y|Z=z]=\frac {\int (\frac {e^{-t}t^y} {y!})(\frac {e^{-t}t^n} {n!}) dt} {\int (\frac {e^{-t}t^n} {n!})dt}$$ 

**I'm not sure about that**. I'll be happy for corrections... @Michael

Comment: @S.R Your discrete case formula is not correct, you cannot say $P[A] = \sum_x P[A|X=x]$.  You would also need to multiply by $P[X=x]$ inside the sum. And of course that would need to be done consistently with double-conditioning. If you are not comfortable with double conditioning, you may want to first simplify $P[Y=y|Z=z]$ using the definition of conditional probability, before conditioning on $X=x$.

Comment: @FormulaWriter : The law of total probability in integral form is $P[A] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P[A|X=x]f_X(x)dx$.  Similarly, the law of total expectation in integral form is $E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E[Y|X=x]f_X(x)dx$.  If you want, you can think of the former as a special case of the latter by defining the indicator variable $Y=1_A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives details on my comments. We have for each $z \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$:
\begin{align}
E[Y|Z=z] &= \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} y P[Y=y|Z=z]\\
&=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} y \frac{P[Y=y,Z=z]}{P[Z=z]}
\end{align}
Now using the law of total probability in integral form (conditioning on $X=x$):
\begin{align}
P[Z=z] &= \int_{0}^{\infty} P[Z=z|X=x]f_X(x)dx\\
P[Y=y,Z=z] &= \int_0^{\infty} P[Y=y,Z=z|X=x]f_X(x)dx
\end{align}

---

Notes:

- We can compute $P[Z=z|X=x]$ from the information given in the question.
- We cannot compute $P[Y=y, Z=z|X=x]$ from the information given in the question. However, if we additionally assume $Y, Z$ are conditionally independent given $X$ (which was stated in later comments), then we can compute it.
- Note that if $Y, Z$ are conditionally independent given $X$, that does not mean $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d\mu(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}dt$  $$P(Z=n|X)=e^{-X}\frac {X^{n}} {n!}.$$ So $$P(Z=n, X \leq x)= {\int_0^{x} {e^{-t} t^{n}}/n!} d\mu(t).$$ This gives $$P( X\leq x|Z=n)=\frac {{\int_0^{x} {e^{-t} t^{n}}/n!} d\mu(t)t} {{\int_0^{\infty} {e^{-t} t^{n}}/n!} d\mu(t)}.$$ Finally $$E(X|Z=n)=\frac {{\int_0^{\infty } t{e^{-t} t^{n}}/n!} d\mu(t)} {{\int_0^{\infty} {e^{-t} t^{n}}/n!} d\mu(t)}.$$

$E(Y|Z)$ cannot be calculated with the given information. However $E(Y|Z)=EY=EX=\lambda$ if you assume that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks! I just though... is the total expectation law needed? the expectation of $Y$ when $X$ is given is simply $X$, so $E[Y|Z]=E[X|Z]$, isn't so?

Comment: Nothing is given about then relationship between $Y$ and $Z$ They might be independent or not. We cannot say $E(Y|Z)=E(X|Z)$. @S.R

Comment: O right... so how this gives $E(Y|Z)$?

Comment: @S.R $E(Y|Z)$ cannot be calculated with the given information.

Comment: So maybe I didn't understand what you said. $Y,Z$ are independent, they just have the same parameter of Poisson distribution, which is $X$. means, unknown. What else is missing to find out $E(Y|Z)$?

Comment: @S.R You did not say anywhere in the question that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. If they are independent then $E(Y|Z)$ is same as $EY$ which is equal to $EX=\lambda$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111175/discussion-between-s-r-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Answer (score 0):

Note, that by the tower property we can get
$$E[Y|Z]=E[E[Y|X]|Z]$$ $E[Y|X]$ is a function of $X$, which simply equals $X$, since $Y\sim Poisson(X)$, and so $E[Y|Z]=E[X|Z]$. From here we can use Murthy's answer to calculate it (I'm not sure, but I think that Michael's answer gives the same result, still it's more complicated to calculate).

Thank you everyone